# Android Spinner getDropDownView repeating items after selection

Tags: android, spinner, kotlin, dropdown

I have the following SpinnerAdapter which successfully brings me a list of my object Discipline with it's correct layout style for both the spinner and the dropdown items. But when I select one of the items, the position 0 text repeats on the selected item position.

```
class ClassesSpinnerAdapter(context: Context, resourceId: Int,
                        val disciplineClasses: List<Discipline>) : ArrayAdapter<Discipline>(context, resourceId, disciplineClasses) {

override fun getItem(position: Int): Discipline {
    return disciplineClasses[position]
}

override fun getCount(): Int {
    return disciplineClasses.size
}

override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
    return super.getItemId(position)
}

override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
    var holder: ClassSpinnerHolder
    var rowView: View

    if (convertView == null) {
        rowView = LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context).inflate(R.layout.classes_spinner_row, parent, false)
        holder = ClassSpinnerHolder()

        holder.classNameTxt = rowView.findViewById(R.id.classes_spinner_text) as TextView?
        holder.classNameTxt?.text = disciplineClasses[position].className.replace("ano", "")
        rowView.tag = holder
    } else {
        holder = convertView.tag as ClassSpinnerHolder
        rowView = convertView
    }
    val discipline: Discipline = disciplineClasses[position];
    if (discipline != null) {
        holder.classNameTxt?.text = disciplineClasses[position].className.replace("ano", "")
    }
    return rowView
}


override fun getDropDownView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
    var holder: ClassSpinnerHolder
    var rowView: View

    if (convertView == null) {
        rowView = LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context).inflate(R.layout.classes_spinner_row, parent, false)
        holder = ClassSpinnerHolder()

        holder.classNameTxt = rowView.findViewById(R.id.classes_spinner_text) as TextView?
        holder.classNameTxt?.text = disciplineClasses[position].className.replace("ano", "")
        rowView.tag = holder
    } else {
        holder = convertView.tag as ClassSpinnerHolder
        rowView = convertView
    }
    return rowView
}

inner class ClassSpinnerHolder() {
    var classNameTxt: TextView? = null
}
```

This is the result that I'm getting:

[image: Initial State]

[image: First Dropdown]

[image: Dropdown after selecting second element]

I kinda solved it by removing the getDropDownView() method and overriding toString on my model class, but I wanted a better solution, I think i'm overriding getDropDownView() in a wrong way, can someone help me out?

Answer (score 2):

In `getDropDownView()`, you only update the values of the view inside your `if (convertView == null)` case. You should always update all values every time the method is called, or else recycled views will have garbage in them.